# Control RTMP chunk size - AWS Cloudfront

Tags: rtmp, amazon-cloudfront

I am developing a website where I am using flow player flash as my video player. I am using AWS(EC2 + S3 + Cloudfront) to manage and store my files. Using cloudfront RTMP I have setup my video streaming.

But the streaming is bit slow, like the buffer takes too long to play small size of video, I have tested my internet speed, and rather then my website other websites like youtube, vimeo  works perfectly fine.

I have enabled cache on cloudfront and also the locations are set for best performance.

Some how is it possible to control chunks size delivered from cloudfront?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think RTMP chunking overheads are large enough to make much difference to your streaming performance, and I would expect that Amazon have configured their Adobe Media Server instances to be optimal by default.

Forgive me for suggesting this, but one possible explanation is that the bitrate of your files is too high and that they'll need to be encoded at lower quality in order to be streamable.